# Is theoretical knowledge necessary to learn RDBMS well?

Tags: rdbms

Is it really necessary to study the database books like [DATABASE SYSTEM CONCEPTS](http://www.mhhe.com/engcs/compsci/silberschatz_bridge/index.mhtml) or [Fundamentals of Database Systems](http://www.pearsonhighered.com/product?ISBN=0321369572) in colleges to learn RDMS?

Why not learn in an informal way with [Beginning Database Design](http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/productCd-0764574906.html) or [Database in Depth](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596100124.do)?

Comment: For what reason? I suspect most would argue this is a "chatty open ended question" and thus against the FAQ.

Answer (score 0):

I would have to say yes, unless you know how the system works you cannot use it to its fullest..

for instance, you need to know what are indexes and how they impact a database before you use them..

its important to learn these concepts, doesn't matter where, could be in college or via the internet.

Comment: I would argue an INDEX is a very *practical* consideration while PRIMARY and CANDIDATE KEYS and NORMAL FORMS are *theoretical* considerations (with high applicability in the practical realm)... but I do concur with the conclusion: how the system works (including the RELATIONAL ALGEBRA) need to be understood in order truly appreciate the relational model in SQL.